# Restoring database on Azure SQL Data Warehouse

Tags: azure-synapse

What variables determine the length of time it takes to restore an Azure SQL Data Warehouse database?

I am creating a new ADW database on a new logical server (in the same Azure region) using the Azure portal and the source specified as the backup for another ADW database (that has ~100TB of uncompressed data loaded to compressed columnar tables).

The Azure Portal reports the status as "Deploying", but am unclear whether this will be an operation taking minutes, hours, or days.

Is there any way to track the progress?

Comment: Process completed in 124 minutes in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Restore time for Azure SQL Data Warehouse is primarily determined by two factors: the size of the database that you are restoring, and the location you are restoring it into. The fastest restore will be in the paired region, the second will be the original region, and finally everywhere else.